# Methods for using Git with Google Colab

Tags: git, google-colaboratory

Are there any recommended methods to integrate git with colab?

For example, is it possible to work off code from google source repositories or the likes?

Neither google drive nor cloud storage can be used for git functionality.

So I was wondering if there is a way to still do it?

Answer (score 121):

If you want to clone a private repository, the quickest way would be to create a [personal access token](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/creating-a-personal-access-token) and select only privileges that your application needs. Then clone command for GitHub would look like:

```
!git clone https://git_token@github.com/username/repository.git
```

Comment: That's close to repeating another answer. But welcome.

Comment: is there a way to dynamically pass username and password. using variables ?

Comment: `u = 'user0'; p = 'pass0'; !git clone https://$u:$p@github.com/$u/repository.git` This should work, `{p} {u}` also work. (!... should start a new line though.)

Comment: If you have `@` in your password, replace it with `%40`.

Comment: Note that the personal access token gives FULL access to private repos. Github doesn't allow you to restrict the token only to read-access.

Comment: The safest way I could find is to use tokens as defined above and take it as variable, such that it's traces are gone after the usage.
`from IPython.display import clear_output;
u = input();
key = input(); 
clear_output() `

run

`!git clone https://$u:$key@github.com/rohitdavas/reponame.git`

Comment: The first solution suggested in this answer does not work anymore as of 13. August 2021. You now have to use personal acces tokens.

Comment: What if I want to pip install?

Answer (score 68):

`git` is installed on the machine, and you can use `!` to invoke shell commands.

For example, to clone a `git` repository:

```
!git clone https://github.com/fastai/courses.git
```

Here's a complete example that clones a repository and loads an Excel file stored therein.
https://colab.research.google.com/notebook#fileId=1v-yZk-W4YXOxLTLi7bekDw2ZWZXWW216

Comment: Is there a way to enter the username and password when cloning private repos ?

Comment: How about getting back the results from Colab into github. I am thinking mostly for checkpoint files to to retrieve the models for inference on a local machine

Comment: Create a token in the Dev tab in your github settings and use this: `! git clone https://TOKEN@github.com/username/repository.git`.

Comment: @AbhaiKollara you can do
`u = 'user'; p = 'pass'; !git clone https://$u:$p@github.com/$u/repository.git`

Answer (score 49):

The very simple and easy way to clone your private **github** repo in Google **colab** is as below.

1. Your password won't be exposed
2. Though your password contains special character also it works
3. Just run the below snippet in Colab cell and it will execute in an interactive way

```
import os
from getpass import getpass
import urllib

user = input('User name: ')
password = getpass('Password: ')
password = urllib.parse.quote(password) # your password is converted into url format
repo_name = input('Repo name: ')

cmd_string = 'git clone https://{0}:{1}@github.com/{0}/{2}.git'.format(user, password, repo_name)

os.system(cmd_string)
cmd_string, password = "", "" # removing the password from the variable
```

Comment: you say password won't be exposed but if one has access to the bash statements executed by colab notebook, they can easily find the password, isn't it? and if you assume that no-one has the access to such bash statements, then how exactly other methods exposes the password?

Comment: @Ritwik the passwords won't be saved on the notebook

Comment: @ohailolcat this assumes no one is reading the log files...

Comment: GitHub removed password authentication on August 13, 2021. This is the error which you will get if you use this: "remote: Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021. Please use a personal access token instead."  Please see https://github.blog/2020-12-15-token-authentication-requirements-for-git-operations/ for more information

Answer (score 19):

You can use ssh protocol to connect your private repository with colab

1. Generate ssh key pairs on your local machine, don't forget to keep
   the paraphrase empty, check this [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-ssh-keys--2).
2. Upload it to colab, check the following [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ty9QQ.png)

   `from google.colab import files`
   `uploaded = files.upload()`
3. Move the ssh kay pairs to /root and connect to git

   - remove previously ssh files
     `! rm -rf /root/.ssh/*`
     `! mkdir /root/.ssh`
   - uncompress your ssh files
     `! tar -xvzf ssh.tar.gz`
   - copy it to root
     `! cp ssh/* /root/.ssh && rm -rf ssh && rm -rf ssh.tar.gz`
     `! chmod 700 /root/.ssh`
   - add your git server e.g gitlab as a ssh known host
     `! ssh-keyscan gitlab.com >> /root/.ssh/known_hosts`
     `! chmod 644 /root/.ssh/known_hosts`
   - set your git account
     `! git config --global user.email "email"`
     `! git config --global user.name "username"`
   - finally connect to your git server
     `! ssh git@gitlab.com`
4. Authenticate your private repository, please check this [Per-repository deploy keys](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ssh/#per-repository-deploy-keys).
5. Use `! git@gitlab.com:{account}/{projectName}.git`
   note: to use push, you have to give write access for
   the public ssh key that you authenticate git server with.

Comment: See also: https://medium.com/@ashkanpakzad/data-into-google-colab-5ddeb4f4e8

Comment: The "per-repository deploy keys" is dead. It would be great if instructions could be added to this answer so that this answer does not depend on external links

Answer (score 18):

In order to protect your account username and password, you can use `getPass` and concatenate them in the shell command:

```
from getpass import getpass
import os

user = getpass('BitBucket user')
password = getpass('BitBucket password')
os.environ['BITBUCKET_AUTH'] = user + ':' + password

!git clone https://$BITBUCKET_AUTH@bitbucket.org/{user}/repository.git
```

Comment: This protection is really weak, in the sense that the plain text password is displayed in the log/output.

Comment: @Simon It only shows the password if you are not able to clone the repository because you get some error.

Comment: In my case, I was getting a 400 (bad request) because of `{user}`, which does not translate to the actual user name.

Answer (score 12):

> Update September 2021 — For security reasons, passwords are now deprecated for github usage. Please use the `Personal Access Token` instead — Go to github.com -> Settings ->Developer Settings -> Personal Access Token and generate a token for the required purpose. Use this in place of your password for all tasks mentioned along this tutorial!

For more details you can also see my article on Medium : https://medium.com/geekculture/using-git-github-on-google-colaboratory-7ef3b76fe61b

None of the answers provide a straight and direct answer like this one :

## GitColab

Probably this is the answer you are looking for..

Works on colab for both public and private repositories and don't change/skip any step: (Replace all `{vars}`)

TL;DR Complete Process:

```
!git clone https://{your_username}:{your_password}@github.com/{destination_repo_username}/{destination_repo_projectname}.git
%cd /content/{destination_repo_username}

!git config --global user.name "{your_username}"
!git config --global user.email "{your_email_id}"
!git config --global user.password "{your_password}"
```

Make Your Changes and then run :

```
!git add .
!git commit -m "{Message}"
!git push
```

### Cloning a Repository :

```
!git clone https://{your_username}:{your_password}@github.com/{destination_repo_username}/{destination_repo_projectname}.git
```

### Change the directory to

Change the directory to {destination_repo_username} using line magic command `%cd` for jupyter notebooks.

```
%cd /content/{destination_repo_username}
```

### Verify!

##### Pull

Sanity Check to see if everything works perfectly!

```
!git pull
```

If no changes were made to the remote git repo after cloning, the following should be the displayed output :

```
Already up to date.
```

##### Status

Similarly check the status of the staged/unstaged changes.

```
!git status
```

It should display this, with the default branch selected :

```
On branch main
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/main'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

### Check Older Logs

Check the previous commits you have made on the repo :

```
!git log -n 4
```

Outputs Git Commit IDs with Logs :

```
commit 18ccf27c8b2d92b560e6eeab2629ba0c6ea422a5 (HEAD -> main, origin/main, origin/HEAD)
Author: Farhan Hai Khan <njrfarhandasilva10@gmail.com>
Date:   Mon May 31 00:12:14 2021 +0530

    Create README.md

commit bd6ee6d4347eca0e3676e88824c8e1118cfbff6b
Author: khanfarhan10 <njrfarhandasilva10@gmail.com>
Date:   Sun May 30 18:40:16 2021 +0000

    Add Zip COVID

commit 8a3a12863a866c9d388cbc041a26d49aedfa4245
Author: khanfarhan10 <njrfarhandasilva10@gmail.com>
Date:   Sun May 30 18:03:46 2021 +0000

    Add COVID Data

commit 6a16dc7584ba0d800eede70a217d534a24614cad
Author: khanfarhan10 <njrfarhandasilva10@gmail.com>
Date:   Sun May 30 16:04:20 2021 +0000

    Removed sample_data using colab (testing)
```

### Make changes in the local repo

Make changes from the local repo directory.

These might include, edditions, deletions, edits.

###### Pro Tip : If you want you can copy paste things from drive to a git repo by:

##### Mount Google Drive:

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/gdrive')
```

##### Copy contents using shutil :

```
import shutil

# For a folder:
shutil.copytree(src_folder,des_folder)

# For a file:
shutil.copy(src_file,des_file)

# Create a ZipFile
shutil.make_archive(archive_name, 'zip', directory_to_zip)
```

### Set Git Credentials

Tell Git Who You Are?

```
!git config --global user.name "{your_username}"
!git config --global user.email "{your_email_id}"
!git config --global user.password "{your_password}"
```

### Check Remote Again

Check if the remote url is set and configured correctly :

```
!git remote -v
```

If configured properly it should output the following :

```
origin  https://{your_username}:{your_password}@github.com/{destination_repo_username}/{destination_repo_projectname}.git (fetch)
origin  https://{your_username}:{your_password}@github.com/{destination_repo_username}/{destination_repo_projectname}.git (push)
```

### Add, Commit, Push

You know what to do.

```
!git add .
!git commit -m "{Message}"
!git push
```

Enjoy!

Answer (score 10):

You can almost use this link:
https://qiita.com/Rowing0914/items/51a770925653c7c528f9

as a summary of the above link you should do this steps:

**1-** connect your google colab runtime to your Google Drive using this commands:

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
```

It would need a authentication process. Do whatever it needs.

**2-** Set `current directory` the path you want to clone the Git project there:

in my example:

```
path_clone = "drive/My Drive/projects"
%cd path_clone
```

don't forget to use `!` in the beginning of `cd` command.

**3-** Clone the Git project:

```
!git clone <Git project URL address>
```

now you would have the cloned Git project in `projects` folder in you Google Drive (*which is also connected to your Google Colab runtime machine*)

**4-** Go to your Google Drive (using browser or etc) and then go to the "projects" folder and open the `.ipynb` file that you want to use in Google Colab.

**5-** Now you have Google Colab runtime with the `.ipynb` that you wanted to use *which is also connected to your Google Drive and all cloned git files are in the Colab runtime's storage.*

**Note:**

1- Check that your Colab runtime is connected to Google Drive. If it's not connected, just repeat the *step #1 above*.

2- Double check by using "pwd" and "cd" commands that the `current directory` is related to the cloned git project in google Drive *(step #2 above)*.

Answer (score 9):

Three steps to use git to sync colab with github or gitlab.

1. Generate a private-public key pair. Copy the private key to the system clibboard for use in step 2. Paste the public key to github or gitlab as appropriate.

   In Linux, ssh-keygen can be used to generate the key-pair in ~/.ssh. The resultant private key is in the file id_rsa, the public key is in the file id_rsa.pub.
2. In Colab, execute

   ```
   key = \
   '''
   paste the private key here 
   (your id_rsa or id_ecdsa file in the .ssh directory, e.g.
   -----BEGIN EC PRIVATE KEY-----
   M..............................................................9
   ...............................................................J
   ..................................==
   -----END EC PRIVATE KEY-----
   '''
   ! mkdir -p /root/.ssh
   with open(r'/root/.ssh/id_rsa', 'w', encoding='utf8') as fh:
       fh.write(key)
   ! chmod 600 /root/.ssh/id_rsa
   ! ssh-keyscan github.com >> /root/.ssh/known_hosts 
   # test setup
   ! ssh -T git@github.com
   # if you see something like "Hi ffreemt! You've successfully 
   # authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access."
   # you are all set. You can tweak .ssh/config for multiple github accounts
   ```
3. Use git to pull/push as usual.

The same idea can be used for rsync (or ssh) bewteen colab and HostA with minor changes:

1. Generate a private-public key pair. Copy the private key to the system clibboard for use in step 2. Paste the public key to authorized_keys in .ssh in HostA.
2. In Colab, execute

   ```
   key = \
   '''
   paste the private key here
   '''
   ! mkdir -p /root/.ssh
   with open(r'/root/.ssh/id_rsa', 'w', encoding='utf8') as fh:
       fh.write(key)
   ! chmod 600 /root/.ssh/id_rsa
   ! ssh -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no root@HostA hostnam  # ssh-keyscan
   ```

HostA >> /root/.ssh/known_hosts does not seem to work with IP.

3. Use rsync to sync files bewtenn colab and HostA as usual.

Answer (score 9):

**Cloning a private repo to google colab :**

Generate a token:

```
Settings -> Developer settings -> Personal access tokens -> Generate new token
```

Copy the token and clone the repo (replace **username** and **token** accordingly)

```
!git clone https://username:token@github.com/username/repo_name.git
```

Answer (score 4):

The solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/53094151/3924118 did not work for me because the expression `{user}` was not being converted to the actual username (I was getting a 400 bad request), so I slightly changed that solution to the following one.

```
from getpass import getpass
import os

os.environ['USER'] = input('Enter the username of your Github account: ')
os.environ['PASSWORD'] = getpass('Enter the password of your Github account: ')
os.environ['REPOSITORY'] = input('Enter the name of the Github repository: ')
os.environ['GITHUB_AUTH'] = os.environ['USER'] + ':' + os.environ['PASSWORD']

!rm -rf $REPOSITORY # To remove the previous clone of the Github repository
!git clone https://$GITHUB_AUTH@github.com/$USER/$REPOSITORY.git

os.environ['USER'] = os.environ['PASSWORD'] = os.environ['REPOSITORY'] = os.environ['GITHUB_AUTH'] = ""
```

If you are able to clone `your-repo`, you should not see any password in the output of this command. **If you get an error, the password could be displayed to the output, so make sure you do not share your notebook whenever this command fails.**

Answer (score 4):

I tried some of the methods here and they all worked well, but an issue I faced was, it became difficult to handle all the git commands and other related commands, for example version control with DVC, within notebook cells. So, I turned to this nice solution, Kora. It is a terminal emulator that can be run with in colab. This gives the ease of usage very similar to a terminal in local machine. The notebook will be still alive and we can edit files and cells as usual. Since this console is temporary, no information is exposed. GitHub login and other commands can be run as usual.

Kora: https://pypi.org/project/kora/

Usage:

```
!pip install kora
```

```
from kora import console
console.start()
```

Answer (score 3):

I finally pulled myself together and wrote a python package for this.

```sh
pip install clmutils  # colab-misc-utils
```

Create a dotenv or .env in /content/drive/MyDrive (if google drive is mounted to drive) or  /content/drive/.env with

```sh
# for git 
user_email = "your-email"
user_name = "your-github-name"
gh_key = "-----BEGIN EC PRIVATE KEY-----
...............................................................9
your github private key........................................J
..................................==
-----END EC PRIVATE KEY-----
"
```

In a Colab cell

```py
from clmutils import setup_git, Settings

config = Settings()
setup_git(
    user_name=config.user_name,
    user_email=config.user_email,
    priv_key=config.gh_key
)
```

You are then all set to do all the `git cloen`, amend code, `git push` stuff as if it were on your own lovely computer at home or at work.

`clmutils` also has a funtion called `setup_ssh_tunnel` to setup a reverse ssh tunnel to Colab. It also reads various keys, username, hostname from the .env file. It's a bit involving. But if you know how to manually set up a revers ssh tunnel to Colab, you would have no problems figuring out what they are used for. Details are available on the github repo (google `clmutils pypi`).

Answer (score 0):

Mount the drive using:

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive/')
```

Then:

```
%cd /content/drive/
```

To clone the repo in your drive

```
!git clone <github repo url>
```

Access other files from the repo(example: helper.py is another file in repo):

```
import imp 
helper = imp.new_module('helper')
exec(open("drive/path/to/helper.py").read(), helper.__dict__)
```

Comment: fatal: could not create work tree dir 'example': Operation not supported

Answer (score 0):

This works if you want to share your repo and colab. Also works if you have multiple repos. Just throw it in a cell.

```
import ipywidgets as widgets
from IPython.display import display
import subprocess

class credentials_input():
    def __init__(self, repo_name):
        self.repo_name = repo_name
        self.username = widgets.Text(description='Username', value='')
        self.pwd = widgets.Password(description = 'Password', placeholder='password here')

        self.username.on_submit(self.handle_submit_username)
        self.pwd.on_submit(self.handle_submit_pwd)        
        display(self.username)

    def handle_submit_username(self, text):
        display(self.pwd)
        return

    def handle_submit_pwd(self, text):
        cmd = f'git clone https://{self.username.value}:{self.pwd.value}@{self.repo_name}'
        process = subprocess.Popen(cmd.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        output, error = process.communicate()
        print(output, error)
        self.username.value, self.pwd.value = '', ''

get_creds = credentials_input('github.com/username/reponame.git')
get_creds
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution based on answer from @Marafon Thiago:

**ATENTION**: In password with special caracters use the respective [encoding](https://fabianlee.org/2016/09/07/git-calling-git-clone-using-password-with-special-character/) of caracter.

Ex `passwd = '@123'` you should type :`passwd = '%40123'`

```
from getpass import getpass
user = getpass('BitBucket user')
password = getpass('BitBucket password')

!git init
!git clone https://{user}:{password}@bitbucket.org/aqtechengenharia/aqtlibpy.git
```

Answer (score 0):

I've recently made a script to automate the steps to clone private repo on https://github.com/tsunrise/colab-github/

You can run the following in colab

```
!wget -q https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tsunrise/colab-github/main/colab_github.py
import colab_github
colab_github.github_auth(persistent_key=True)
```

And then clone your repo using SSH method:

```py
!git clone git@github.com:<your_username>/<your_private_repo>.git
```